# Azure Cognitive Search: queryLanguage Parameter Not Affecting Semantic Search Results

Tags: azure, semantic-search

I am working with Azure Cognitive Search and have set up an index with content in both English and German. I'm attempting to perform semantic search with different `queryLanguage` parameters to retrieve language-specific results. However, I'm encountering an issue where the `queryLanguage` parameter does not seem to influence the search results, and I'm getting identical results for different language settings.

Here are two example queries I'm using:

**Query 1**:

```json
{
  "count": true,
  "search": "auto",
  "queryType": "semantic",
  "queryLanguage": "de-de",
  "semanticConfiguration": "default"
}
```

**Query 2**:

```json
{
  "count": true,
  "search": "auto",
  "queryType": "semantic",
  "queryLanguage": "en-us",
  "semanticConfiguration": "default",
  "select": "id, chunk_id, content"
}
```

Despite specifying different `queryLanguage` values, the search results remain the same. I expected that changing the `queryLanguage` parameter would affect the results to reflect the language-specific content. How can I make the `queryLanguage` parameter work correctly in semantic search to retrieve language-specific results?

Any guidance or insights into configuring the `queryLanguage` parameter for semantic search in multilingual scenarios would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Information**:

- My index field stores content in both English and German.

Expected Behavior:
The queryLanguage parameter should influence the semantic search results, ensuring that queries in distinct languages return language-appropriate results. In this case, German and English queries should yield different results based on the language of the content.

Actual Behavior:
The queryLanguage parameter does not appear to affect the semantic search results, resulting in identical outcomes regardless of the specified queryLanguage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined language analyzers for English and German? Or are you simply indexing random content that contain either language?

It is not clear what you do. A concrete example would help.

Comment: The content in the index field was only in English and German, and the analyzer used was `en.lucene`. The content pertained to the history of automotive progress, and consequently, the query contained words present in both English and German.

When I set the `queryLanguage` to `de-de` or 'en-us' I expected the results to be semantically ranked as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/preview-api/search-documents?view=rest-searchservice-2023-10-01-preview#querylanguage). However, the results were always the same.

Comment: I conducted numerous tests and couldn't confirm that the `queryLanguage` parameter had any impact on semantic ranking, captions, highlighting.

I would also appreciate it if you could describe how the index parameters should be set, the type of content that should be present, and provide an example query that clearly demonstrates the influence of the `queryLanguage` parameter on semantic ranking, captions, highlighting

Thank you for your assistance in helping me understand and resolve this issue.